# How would I find arc length of $\dfrac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$ without hyperbolic f(x)'s

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, arc-length

How do you find the arc length of $\dfrac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$  from [0, 2] without using hyperbolic functions?

Using the formula 
$$\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx$$ I run into a problem where I can't get from

$$y' = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left({e^x - e^{-x}}\right)$$

to

$$1 + (y')^2 = \biggr(\frac{1}{2}\left({e^x + e^{-x}}\right)\biggr)^2$$

The book and other solutions I've seen make this step, but I don't follow. Shouldn't I end up with,

$$1 + (y')^2 = \biggr(\frac{1}{2}\left({e^x - e^{-x}}\right)\biggr)^2 + 1$$

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe open the bracket and see if those two are equal to each other ?(hint: they are equal)

Comment: $$\biggr(\frac{1}{2}\left({e^x - e^{-x}}\right)\biggr)^2 + 1=\dfrac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}-2}{4}+1=\biggr(\frac{1}{2}\left({e^x + e^{-x}}\right)\biggr)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\quad{\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx=\\
\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2}\left({e^x - e^{-x}}\right))^2 + 1}dx=
\\\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(\left({e^x - e^{-x}}\right)^2 +4)}dx=
\\\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(({e^{2x} +e^{-2x}-2e^x e^{-x}} +4)}dx=
\\\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(({e^{2x} +e^{-2x}-2} +4)}dx=
\\\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}((e^{2x} +e^{-2x}+2)}dx=
\\\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}((e^{2x} +e^{-2x}+2e^x e^{-x})}dx=
\\\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(e^{x} +e^{-x})^2}dx=
\\=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{(\frac{e^{x} +e^{-x}}{2})^2}dx
\\=\int_{a}^{b} (\frac{e^{x} +e^{-x}}{2})dx}$$